# Resolver erro de lógica

Tags: c

Estou fazendo uns exercícios da faculdade, porém eu estou tendo um erro de lógica nesse exercício:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*usuario entra com um numero, o programa devera imprimir o maior numero primo entre 1 e o numero digitado*/

int main()
{
    int aux, num, i, j, cont=0, rest=0;

    printf("digite um nume:\n");
    scanf("%i", &num);

    for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
          rest=i%j;

          if(rest==0)
                cont++;

          if(cont==2)
            aux=i;
        }
    }

    printf("O maior numero primo entre 0 e %d sera %d", num, aux);

    return 0;
}
```

Como resolver o problema?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encontrei 2 erros no teu código:

1- O contador `cont` tem que ser reinicializado a cada iteração do primeiro `for`:

```
for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
{
    cont = 0;
    for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
```

2- No segundo `for`, você verifica se `cont` é igual a 2 e assume que aquele número é primo. Mas se ele encontrar outra divisão perfeita depois, `cont` vai virar 3, 4, 5... e aquele número não vai ser primo. Então, tu tem que verificar se `cont` é igual a 2 no final do `for`, após passar todos os números:

```
if(cont==2 && j == i)
    aux=j;
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Lucas, deu certo, corrigido, compreendi o meu erro e a solução.

Answer (score 5):

Dá para fazer de forma mais eficiente:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num, aux, cont;
    aux = 0;
    printf("digite um nume:\n");
    scanf("%i", &num);
    for (int i = num; i >= 2; --i) {
        cont = 0;
        for (int j = 2; j < sqrt(i) + 1; ++j) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                cont++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (cont == 0) {
            aux = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("O maior numero primo entre 0 e %d sera %d", num, aux);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/c4PFwH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Logic). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Logic.c).

É melhor começar de um número mais alto, assim achar mais rapidamente um primo. Começando do 1 você tem que passar por todos os primos até descobrir qual é o maior. Desta forma o primeiro primo que encontrar já é o resultado esperado.

Comment: bigown obrigado por mostrar dessa forma, testei e gostei bastante testei e irei apresentar ao meu professor para dar uma olhada.

Comment: Não seria mais eficiente fazer `j*j <= i` do que calcular a raiz quadrada?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é provável.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz de uma maneira mais simples:

Isuário entra com um número, o programa devera imprimir o maior numero primo entre 1 e o número digitado

```
int main() {  
int i, num;

    printf("digite um nume:\n");  
    scanf("%i", &num);  

//já que é o primeiro primo maior entre 0 e num, é mais lógico começar de num;  

    for(i=num;i>2;i--) {  

if ((i%2!=0) & (i%3!=0) && (i%5!=0)) {

   printf("O maior numero primo entre 0 e %d sera %d", num, i);
}
}

    return 0;
}
```