# Loop infinito tentando calcular se o número é primo

Tags: c, algoritmo

Estou sem ideia de como vou determinar a condição do `for` para números primos. Sempre acabo em *looping*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int num = 1, primo;
    do {

        printf("Informe um numero primo maior que 1:");
        scanf("%d", &primo);

    } while (primo <= 1);



    for (num=1; num<=primo; primo++){

       if (primo%num==0)
           printf("Numero primo",primo);
       else
           printf("Numero não primo",primo);
    }

}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 10):

Para programar tem que pensar em tudo como o problema realmente é. Não adianta chutar coisas. Isto não é programar. Uma das coisas que ajudam clarificar os pensamentos é manter o código bem organizado, fácil de ler e entender, incluindo dando nomes para variáveis que são significativos, que indiquem o que realmente aquele nome representa. Tem que pensar bem o nome correto para tudo, caso contrário gera confusões como visto neste código.

Você só consegue saber se um número é primo ou não depois de ter testado todas possibilidades, não tem como saber testando cada uma das possibilidades, então a verificação não pode estar dentro do laço.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, numero;
    do {
        printf("Informe um numero primo maior que 1:");
        scanf("%d", &numero);
    } while (numero <= 1);
    for (i = 2; i < numero; i++) {
        if (numero % i == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (numero == i) {
        printf("Numero primo %d", numero);
    } else {
        printf("Numero não primo %d", numero);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/1bH3Ai). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/oerlwxya-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/PrimeInfinite.c).

Comment: No for, acredito que seja `i < numero`, não?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar sim, claro, obrigado.

Comment: Ou você poderia otimizar o código para `i*i <= numero`, já que você só precisa ir até `numero^(1/2)` pra saber se ele é primo ou não. (:

Comment: Eu não quis complicar para ele que está começando neste caso. Eu já tenho uma resposta que eu uso esta técnica. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50500/101

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar se um número é primo ou não, você não precisa fazer todas as verificações de 2 até n. Porque o número 2 é o único número primo par, logo, pra verificar se 11 é primo ou não, você só precisa verificar até 5,porque os números restantes são múltiplos de 1, 2, 3, 4 e 5, ou seja, 3x2=6, 4x2=8 e 5x2=10, como todos os números naturais multiplicados por 2 são pares, logo não serão primos, com exceção de 2.Então assim, se você for verificar se um número muito grande é primo ou não, você vai obter o resultado mais rápido.

```
int isPrimeNumber(int num){
    if(num <= 1){
        return 0; //Retorna falso
    } else {
        int quant = num / 2;
        for(; quant >= 2; --quant)
            if(num % quant == 0)
                return 0; //Retorna falso
        return 1; //Retorna verdadeiro
    }
}
```

Código no ideone: [Número primo](http://ideone.com/HMwBVy)