# Problemas com lógica em um programa

Tags: c, for

```
    //EXERCICIO 103
    //VERIFICAR SE UM NÚMERO É PRIMO

    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<locale.h>
    main(){
        setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
        int n,k,cont,div;
        printf("Informe um número: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        if(n>0){              //SE n FOR MAIOR QUE 0, O PROGRAMA EXECUTA
            for(k=n; k>0 ;k--){ 
                div = n % k;   //DIVIDE PARA VERIFICAR SE É EXATA 
                if(div==0){  //SE FOR EXATA ADICIONA 1 NO CONTADOR
                    cont++;
                }
            }

            if(cont==2){
                printf("%d é primo.",n);
            }
            else{
                printf("%d não é primo",n);
            }

        }
        else{
            printf("Número inválido!");
        }
    }
```

Já testei o programa várias vezes e testei a lógica, aparentemente está certa mas sempre retorna que o número não é primo. Não consigo achar o erro, por favor me ajudem.

Comment: Inicialize a variável cont antes de entrar no loop. `cont = 0`

Comment: Deu certinho, obrigadoo

Comment: Bem mais eficiente: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/85568/101. Esse mais ainda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50500/101.

Answer (score 0):

Paulo, para utilizar o comando `cont++`, a variável precisa ter sido inicializada primeiro.
Para resolver o problema, basta inicializar a variável no começo do código, como zero por exemplo: `cont = 0;`

Comment: Valeu! Não sabia que precisava inicializar antes. Deu certinho.